# Retrieve error codes only for IIS Web Application

Tags: iis

Instead of getting an error page I would like to get error codes only (e.g. 404) for a Web Application in IIS. How can I disable error pages on a Web Application level?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you are asking but you can set <customError mode="Off" /> in web.config; this would show the complete error description on page.